# Can't find my pickle file in a folder

Tags: python-2.7, pickle, jupyter-notebook

l'm working on jupyter (ipython notebook)
l stored my file usig pickle l succeeded to store it then load(read it) it in jupyter but l can't find it in my folder. What's wrong ?

```
import os
pickle.dump(features,open(os.getcwd()+"\home\Desktop\features.obj","wb"))

pickle.load(open(os.getcwd()+"\home\Desktop\features.obj","rb"))
```

Comment: Print the directory you used, then check it.

Comment: thank you it's working l'm not in the same directory